# problema al enviar mail desde localhost con phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, gmail

Tengo instalado PHP v5.6.25 (utilizo la versión de 64x) y wampserver v3.0.6, Apache 2.4.23. He realizado algunas modificaciones de puertos ya que he seguido varios tutoriales en youtube pero no recuerdo puntualmente que lineas he modificado.

Archivo php.ini www.dropbox.com/s/vnoxv38qqa67oez/php.ini?dl=0

Estoy intentando hacer un sistema de envío de correos usando phpmailer, usando como host "smtp.gmail.com" he habilitado el acceso de aplicaciones menos seguras de mi cuenta de gmail (myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps).

Mi archivo PHP es el siguiente:

```
<?php
// This example shows settings to use when sending via Google's Gmail servers.
//

//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;

//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();

//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
// use
// $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
// if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6

//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587;

//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = "*******@gmail.com";

//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "+++++++++";

//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('no-reply@midominio.com', 'No responder');

//Set an alternative reply-to address
//$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');

//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('*********@gmail.com', 'Nombre Destinatario');

//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';

$nombre='Federico Lorca';
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->Body = "<h1>Prueba de correo</h1><br><br>Mensaje de prueba enviado por {$nombre} con phpmailer en formato html<br>";

//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

//Attach an image file
//$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}  ?>
```

Muestra el siguiente error:

[image]

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el error como texto? No es legible

Comment: A partir de PHP 5.2.10 tendrás este error si no tienes certificados válidos. Lo puedes resolver con este código: `$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);` o escribiendo una clase perosnalizada de SMTP. Ver: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting y también: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Overriding-the-SMTP-class

Comment: @A.Cedano Muchas gracias amigo! estuve una semana tratando de solucionar esto, has resuelto mi problema :) como puedo puntuarte? soy nuevo en este foro. Estoy muy feliz :D

Comment: Me alegro... Escribiré una respuesta con la solución. La puedes marcar como aceptada haciendo clic en el signo de cotejo que aparecerá a la izquierda de la respuesta y también podrás votarla favorablemente dando clic en la fecha gris que apunta hacia arriba, cuando aparezca la respuesta, claro.

Comment: @A.Cedano perfecto :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partir de PHP 5.2.10, cuando intentamos usar PHPMailer sin tener un certificado válido  [tendremos derecho a un error](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) parecido a este:

> Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code
>   1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

y por supuesto, nuestro código no funcionara.

### ¿Cómo resolver este problema?

La **mejor solución** sería contar con un certificado válido.

Pero cuando esto no es posible, se puede agregar lo siguiente a nuestro código:

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
```

Otra posible solución que dan los creadores de PHP Mailer es crear nuestra propia clase personalizada, de la cual [muestran un ejemplo en este enlace](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Overriding-the-SMTP-class).

### Soluciones equivocadas

**No toques el archivo `php.ini`para hacer que PHPMailer deje de dar este error.** Ya que PHP tiene sus razones para haberse vuelto más exigente en cuanto a los certificados SMTP. Pero eso es otra historia...

> You can also change these settings globally in your php.ini, but
>   that's a really bad idea; PHP 5.6 made this change for very good
>   reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Añade a los parametros el siguiente comando, tal vez con esto se solucione.

```
$mail->Helo('www.gmail.com');
```